# Como matar todas os dialogs na tela de uma só vez?

Tags: android, dialog

Eu faço uma verificação e jogo 3 dialogs na tela, porém se o usuário cancelar um deles, todos devem fechar. Alguém sabe como fazer isso? nem sei se é possível. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Pode postar uma previa do seu código?

Answer (score 1):

Claro que é possível, se você tem uma referência aos três dialogs criados, basta você interceptar o click em um deles e fazer algo como:

```
dialog1.dismiss();
dialog2.dismiss();
dialog3.dismiss();
```

Bem, um exemplo completo seria assim:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setMessage("Exemplo");
        builder1.setPositiveButton("Sim", null);
        builder1.setNegativeButton("Não", null);
        final AlertDialog dialog1 = builder1.show();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder2.setMessage("Exemplo");
        builder2.setPositiveButton("Sim", null);
        builder2.setNegativeButton("Não", null);
        final AlertDialog dialog2 = builder2.show();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder3.setMessage("Exemplo");
        builder3.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog3, int i) {
                dialog3.dismiss();
                dialog1.dismiss();
                dialog2.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder3.setNegativeButton("Não", null);
        AlertDialog dialog3 = builder3.show();
```

Ao clicar no sim do `dialog3`, os três dialogs serão fechados.